# Should I optimize for Adsense eCPM or Adsense Revenue?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense, theme, split-testing

I'm split testing, and one skin has a higher revenue, while the other skin has a higher eCPM. Which one should I choose? If I select the higher eCPM, I assume that any future enhancements will bring a higher revenue, but then revenue now is real money.

Comment: Also, how many samples before it is a statistically significant difference? The splitter isn't capable of multivariate testing.